# Sum and group By in XQUERY

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have two XML Files for represent a market, 
first File is bills that contains bills information type (Sale,Purchase) this is the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
 <bill>
     <billid>1</billid>
     <billtype>sales</billtype>
     <billdate>10/10/2013</billdate>
 </bill>
  <bill>
     <billid>2</billid>
     <billtype>Purchase</billtype>
     <billdate>15/10/2013</billdate>
 </bill>
  <bill>
     <billid>3</billid>
     <billtype>Purchase</billtype>
     <billdate>20/10/2013</billdate>
 </bill>
  <bill>
     <billid>4</billid>
     <billtype>sales</billtype>
     <billdate>16/10/2013</billdate>
 </bill>
</root>
```

and the second file contains the products information in that bills and its like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <itembill>
   <itembill_id>1</itembill_id>
   <itemid_ref>2</itemid_ref>
   <billid_ref>2</billid_ref>
   <price>20000</price> 
  </itembill>
   <itembill>
   <itembill_id>2</itembill_id>
   <itemid_ref>3</itemid_ref>
   <billid_ref>3</billid_ref>
   <price>250000</price> 
  </itembill>
  <itembill>
   <itembill_id>4</itembill_id>
   <itemid_ref>1</itemid_ref>
   <billid_ref>2</billid_ref>
   <price>140000</price> 
  </itembill>
  <itembill>
   <itembill_id>5</itembill_id>
   <itemid_ref>2</itemid_ref>
   <billid_ref>1</billid_ref>
   <price>10000</price> 
  </itembill>
</root>
```

where billid_ref is the foreign key (billid) ,

the question is:
i want a **X query** DO a **SUM** for the price **group by** bill type
how can i do this?!

and i have tried this:

```
<catalog>
   { 
     for $x in doc('bills')//bill,
     $y in doc('itembills')//itembill where $y/billid_ref = $x/billid and $x/billtype = "Purchase"

     return
        <item >
           {
sum ($y/price/text())
           }

        </item>

   }
<catalog>
```

but not working well the result was:

```
<catalog>
  <item>20000</item>
  <item>140000</item>
  <item>250000</item>
  <item>30000</item>
<catalog>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than "not working well"? What result do you get?

Comment: ok 

<catalog>
  <item>20000</item>
  <item>140000</item>
  <item>250000</item>
  <item>30000</item>
<catalog>

Comment: You want to "by subtract[ing] purchases from Sales" -- but are not doing it anywhere. Also post expected output, helps a lot when explaining what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a grouping operator in xquery 3.0, but not in xquery 1.0.  In 1.0, you can create a sequence of values and sum them like this:

```
<catalog>{
for $x in doc('bills')//bill
  let $y := doc('itembills')//itembill where $y/billid_ref = $x/billid and $x/billtype = "Purchase"  
 return
    <item >
       { sum ($y/price/text()) }
    </item>
}</catalog>
```

but you won't be able to group by billtype without another loop (for billtype in ... )

Comment: thank you very much ,, its worked and the result was:
<catalog>
  <item>450000</item>
  <item>450000</item>
</catalog>